# Use Qt to parse XML and modified value of some member

Tags: c++, xml, qt

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <title>myproj</title>
  <note>some note</note>
  <!-- our entry -->

  <entry>
    <desc>Camera Position</desc>
    <identifier>f_f</identifier>
    <type>CameraExtrinsics</type>
    <typeentry>
      <member>pos_x</member>
      <value>-861</value>
    </typeentry>
    <typeentry>
      <member>pos_y</member>
      <value>0</value>
    </typeentry>
  </entry>

</configuration>
```

How can I using Qt modify the value of member `pos_x` (from `-861`) to a desired value (let say 50). The goal is that at the end, if I open my xml file using a text editor, I will see that pos_x has the value 50.

Currently I come up with this code which parse the file, butI don't know how to go further

```
QFile* xmlFile = new QFile("file.xml");

if (!xmlFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
   std::cout << " opening xml file failed " << std::endl;
}

QXmlStreamReader* xmlReader = new QXmlStreamReader(xmlFile);
```

( I'm using qt 4.8 and avoid c++11 or higher, if possible)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The answer you have mentioned does not explain how to access specify element and then modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing a document to add a new node or modify a value is quite the same thing:

```
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDomElement>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QDomText>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QDomDocument document;

    QString const content("<root><foo><bar>spam</bar></foo></root>")
    if (!document.setContent(content, false))
    {
        qDebug() << "failed to parse file";
        return 0;
    }

    QDomElement docEle = document.documentElement(); // get root node
    QDomElement foo = docEle.firstChildElement("foo"); // get foo node inside the root
    QDomElement bar = foo.firstChildElement("bar"); // get the bar node inside foo
    QDomNode txt = bar.firstChild(); // get the current text
    QDomNode newTxt = document.createTextNode("Booh!"); // create a new text node

    bar.replaceChild(newTxt, txt); // replace the current text node by the new text
    qDebug() << document.toString();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're using a straightforward xml file. How will the solution looks like for the xml file provided in the question? How to navigate the xml file and locate the specific element you want to modify ?

Comment: `QDomDocument::setContent` accept a `QIODevice` (such as QFile) as parameter. Replace the variable `content` by your `xmlfile`variable. By the way, don't use dynamic allocation (assignment with new) when you don't need it.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. How do I  1)acess `member`  2)modify it value? You might have answer the 2). but the entire problem is not solved

Comment: My example shows ho mw to access to a specific node and change its text value. I commented my code but I don't see what is missing.