# Replace an existing xml tag value occurs unexpected change in xml file

Tags: xml, qt, c++11

I want to replace a value of a xml tag. I can replace the value by using QDom, however I am getting a change in my xml file just after that change.

I am working with qt and I have tried with "QDOM" to replace the tag value and save it using "QTextStream".

```
QFile myFile(QLatin1String(my_FILE));
if (liceFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    QDomDocument doc;
    doc.setContent(&myFile);
    QDomElement parentEle = doc.firstChildElement("Root");
    QDomNode myValue= parentEle.firstChildElement("Mytag");
    myValue.firstChild().setNodeValue("Hey");
    QTextStream stream(&myFile);
    doc.save(stream, 4);
    myFile.close();
```

The xml file:

```
"<Root>
   <Mytag>Hello</Mytag>
   <User></User>
   <Pass>121</Pass>"
```

If I replacing  the value of "Mytag". 
    Output after replace.

```
"<Root>
  <Mytag>Hey</Mytag>
  <User/>
  <Pass>121</Pass>"
```

I can not understand why  tag changed from `<User>Mr<User/>` to   `<User/>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Qt to parse XML and modified value of some member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001940/use-qt-to-parse-xml-and-modified-value-of-some-member)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save your `XML` document, the entire document is written to the output file.
So, `QDomDocument` will save `<User></User>` which is an empty element with his default empty element style i.e. `<User/>`.

hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However It does not work. When the " <User></User>" value is not empty the solution works. In my case that tag value is empty. Solution 2: if I make  QIODevice::WriteOnly, I think QTextstream does not work. It erases every thing from xml file.